# what could be the process flow for trajectory planning of 6DOF manipulator using arduino?

Tags: ros, arduino, manipulator, tutorial, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to make exactly what this video shows - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfP6J9Bxt2w . can anybody tell me how to interlink arduino with ros? which tutorial i need to study? i've just finished studying rosserial_arduino, but i dont understand how to make visual model and simulation...how can i do that? any suggestion for it to study?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211275/what-could-be-the-process-flow-for-trajectory-planning-of-6dof-manipulator-using-arduino?/) by [baiju](https://answers.ros.org/users/22012/baiju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2015-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try looking into this:

http://moveit.ros.org/

---

Originally posted by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) with karma: 101 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1